# Is there any easy way to restructure react project folder path?

Tags: reactjs

Eg. I have a component called CompA with shared lib, right now I want to move the lib path to other place, then I have to update all path under the CompA, is there any easy way to achieve it?

Original folder structure

```
Component
- CompA
-- Common
-- Logic
-- Dialogs
- CompB
- Lib
```

New Structure

```
Component
- CompA
-- Common
-- Logic
-- Dialogs
- CompB
Lib
```

I'm thinking of using a configuration file to setup a LIB_PATH constant, but I'm facing the problem that how I can setup the reference path for the LIB_PATH, since there is no __dirname for js project.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: Just use your IDE to move the file, and it should update the relative references.

Comment: @lux, do you mean IntelliJ refactor tool? Good suggestion, but if there is any programming way?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to program this when the IDE does it for you automatically.

Comment: @lux Atom actually dosen't do anything about moving file; for reusable purpose, what if we move comp from project A to project B?